# Max execution time issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, execution-time

I want to increase the maximum execution & input time for my PHP scripts. I added the following two lines to my .htaccess file located at the document root:

```
php_value max_execution_time 8000
php_value max_input_time 4000
```

It works perfectly well on my development server, but on the production server (GoDaddy) I'm getting a 500 internal server error. Why is it so?

Comment: if you swap out your .htaccess is the 500 error still occurring? it's possible that something else is causing it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you should try putting the same code into a php5.ini file instead of a .htaccess file. Godaddy servers are usually setup to accept configuration settings from php5.ini file.

Make a text file with the filename  as "php5.ini" and put the following in it:

```
max_execution_time 8000
max_input_time 4000
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember right from a client with GoDaddy ages ago, you have to use your own php.ini file since their config doesn't support PHP flags in .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1):

`php_value max_input_time 4000O`- that last character is a capital `O`, not a zero `0`.